# Flutter commands are not running

Tags: flutter, command

I'm trying to run the flutter commands but it gives me this error

```
Flutter failed to write to a file at
"/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/3.0.3/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_version_check.sta
mp".
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has
read/write permissions for the current user.
Try running:
  sudo chown -R $(whoami)
  /usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/3.0.3/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_version_check.st
  amp
```

please help how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give permission to your username to access that folder

```
sudo chown -R <your_username> /flutter_sdk_path/
```

Answer (score 0):

Check permission for the mentioned directory via:

```
ls -l /usr/local/Caskroom/flutter
```

Then run this command:

```
sudo chown -R [user]:root /opt/flutter
```